# If $f(x)=1$ for $x \geq 0$, $f(x)=-1$ for $x < 0$, what is the correct way to draw the graph of $f'$ at $0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider $f$ and $f'$ as depicted in the picture below

[image]

Is the correct depiction of $f'$ the second or the third graph?

$f(0)$ is $>0$ in the first graph, and if the derivative is defined as a limit from above at 0, then $f'$ exists at 0.

The derivative limit from below doesn't exist, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second graph is correct.  The derivative is not defined at $x=0$, so there should be a hole there.  The derivative is defined as a limit as $h\to 0$ but we allow $h$ to be either positive or negative.  The limit of the derivative does exist at $x=0$ and is $0$ regardless of whether the points near $0$ that you consider are greater than or less than $0$.

Comment: You say "the derivative is not defined at $x=0$ and that there should be a hole there". Graph 3 does not have a hole at $0$, so why do you say it is the correct one?

Comment: @evianpring:  sorry, I thought there were two graphs of $f$, so the first graph of $f'$ was the third in order.  Fixed.

Comment: Now that we have that cleared up, the context of why I asked this question is a problem in Spivak's Calculus: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4454410/f-is-diff-in-some-interval-containing-a-f-is-discontinuous-at-a-can

Comment: @evianpring:  Did you see Ned's comment?  Your example violates the assumptions of the theorem.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that $f$ is differentiable in an interval containing $a$ so it is also continuous. My silly mistake.