# $f$ is diff. in some interval containing $a$, $f'$ is discontinuous at $a$. Can one-sided limits of form $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f'(x)$ both exist?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The following is a problem from ch. 11 of Spivak's Calculus

> 61. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable in some interval containing $a$, but that $f'$ is discontinuous at $a$. Prove the following:
>
> (a) The one-sided limits $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f'(x)$ and
> $\lim\limits_{x \to a^-} f'(x)$ cannot both exist. (This is just a
> minor variation on Theorem 7).

For the record, here is Theorem 7

> **Theorem 7:** Suppose $f$ is continuous at $a$, $f'(x)$ exists for all
> $x$ in some interval containing $a$, except perhaps for $x=a$.
> Suppose, moreover, that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f'(x)$ exists. Then
> $f'(a)$ also exists, and
>
> $$f'(a)=\lim\limits_{x \to a} f'(x)$$

Consider the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1, x \geq 0 \\ 0, x<0 \end{cases}$$

Then

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases} 0, x > 0 \\ 0, x<0 \end{cases}$$

[image]

$f'$ is not defined at $0$, thus it is not continuous there. It is defined for all $x$ in some interval around $0$.

Also $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f'(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to a^-} f'(x)$ both exist and equal 0.

At first glance, $f$ seems to me to be a counterexample to the claim in $61 (a)$.

But Spivak asks us to prove that $61 (a)$ is a true statement. What is wrong with the supposed counterexample?

Comment: Theorem $7$ says "Suppose $f$ is continuous at $a$ ...."

Comment: 61 (a) assumes $f$ is differentiable in some interval containing $a$. Therefore, $f$ must be continuous at $a$. My mistake.

Comment: Darboux' theorem ensures that $f'$ satisfies the intermediate value property.

Comment: Both theorems require $f'(a)$ to exist. In your example, it does not exist. Your $f$ is not differentiable is a neighborhood of $0$ because it is not differentiable at $0$ itself. The result is about what can happen when $f'$ exists, but is not continuous.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Theorem 7 does not seem to require $f'(a)$ to exist. In fact, the Theorem answers the question of what happens to $f'$ at $a$. Here is my full interpretation of this theorem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4454898/f-cont-at-a-f-exists-in-interval-containing-a-except-possibly-at-a/4454904#4454904