# $f$ cont. at $a$, $f'$ exists in interval containing $a$ (except possibly at $a$), $l=\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f'(x)$ exists. Does $f'(a)=l$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, proof-explanation

This question regards the following theorem (as stated in Spivak's Calculus):

> **Theorem 7:** Suppose $f$ is continuous at $a$, $f'(x)$ exists for all
> $x$ in some interval containing $a$, except perhaps for $x=a$.
> Suppose, moreover, that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f'(x)$ exists. Then
> $f'(a)$ also exists, and
>
> $$f'(a)=\lim\limits_{x \to a} f'(x)$$

This theorem seems relatively simple yet to me it is difficult to wrap my head around what it is actually saying and why it would be useful.

Let me cut to the chase with my questions.

1. Is my below interpretation of the theorem correct?
2. If we slightly alter the theorem to use a limit from above, can we still conclude something about $f'(a)$?

Details provided below.

**Here is my interpretation of what it is saying.**

Consider a function $f$ and an interval containing a point $a$. We know that $f$ is continuous at $a$ and differentiable at all other points in the interval. We're wondering about differentiability of $f$ at this single point $a$.

However, we do know that $f'$ approaches some limit near $a$.

That is, $\lim\limits_{x \to x_1}\frac{f(x)-f(x_1)}{x-x_1}$ does exist for any $x_1$ in an interval around $a$, but not including $a$. Also, the limit of this limit as $x_1 \to a$ exists.

Now consider this limit at $a$, ie $\lim\limits_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. Theorem 7 proves that this limit exists.

The argument is that when we are computing the limit above, we are considering expressions of form $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$, where $f$ is differentiable in $(a,x)$. No matter how close $x$ gets to $a$, the MVT tells us there is always another point $a<\alpha_x<x$ such that $f'(\alpha_x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

But then what is happening is that our original limit $\lim\limits_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ is actually computing the same thing as $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f'(\alpha_x)$, which is the same thing as $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f'(x)$.

That is, the limit we are interested in, $\lim\limits_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$, equals $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f'(x)$.

But that means that $f'(a)$ exists.

**Now let's' make the argument for a variation of Theorem 7.**

> Suppose $f$ is continuous at $a$, $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ in some
> interval containing $a$ except perhaps for $x=a$. Suppose that
> $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f'(x)$ exists.
>
> Then $\lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ exists and equals
> $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f'(x)$

**Here is an attempt to prove this.**

For sufficiently small $h$, $f$ is differentiable on $(a,a+h)$ and continuous on $[a,a+h]$.

The Mean Value Theorem tells us that $\exists \alpha_h, \alpha_h \in (a,a+h) \land f'(\alpha_h)=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$.

Therefore,

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} f'(\alpha_h)=\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f'(x)\tag{1}$$

**Can we equate $(1)$ to $f'(a)$?**

Comment: $f(x)=|x|$ does not obey (1) at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your interpretation looks good to me.
2. You cannot modify the theorem to be

$$\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f'(x)=l$$

implies $f'(x)=l$. For example, take $f(x)=|x|$ and $a=0$. Then

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}1=1$$

But

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)\text{ DNE}$$

since for $x\neq 0$ we have

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases} 
      -1 & x< 0 \\
      1 & x> 0 
   \end{cases}$$

Comment: What you are saying is that I can't equate $(1)$ to $f'(a)$. But the variation of Theorem 7, as it is written above, is still true as is, correct?

Comment: Your variation is correct. I am slightly confused by your question, because I believed (1) was simply asking if your understanding of Theorem 7 was correct (which I believe is the case). I'm not sure what you are saying when you say "What you are saying is that I can't equate (1) to $f′(a)$"?

Comment: The last line in my posted question is "can we equate $(1)$ to $f'(a)$?". The variation of theorem 7 has as conclusion that $\lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f'(x)$. This latter conclusion is still true for $f(x)=|x|$ at $0$.

Comment: What you are saying in your answer is that we can't take the extra step (which is taken in the original Theorem 7) of equating $\lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f'(x)$ to $f'(a)$, because even though we were able to figure out that the limit $\lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ exists, we cannot conclude anything about the corresponding limit from below $\lim\limits_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Here is the context for why I asked the above question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4455038/spivak-calculus-ch-11-prob-61a-f-diff-in-interval-containing-a-f-dis